# .NET Core application Use Azure Redis Cache with Load Balancers

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-redis-cache, azure-load-balancer

I have asp.net core web application hosted on Azure. 
I've configured Azure Redis Cache to use it as a session store. It works well on Dev where Load Balancer is not configured.
 
Our UAT & Prod have load balancers configured. And there Redis Session store is not working as expected. I’m facing issue of frequent session timeout.

Following is the current implementation:
**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
options.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString(“RedisCache”);
options.InstanceName = “SampleInstance”;
});
services.AddSession(options =>
{
options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
options.Cookie.Name = “SessionCookie”;
});
```

Added `app.UseSession();` in Configure method.

**In HomeController Login Action**,

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString(“UserId”, loggedInUser.UserId.ToString());
HttpContext.Session.SetString(“CompanyCode”, loggedInUser.CompanyCode.ToString());
```

It works in Local & Dev, but fails on environment where Load Balancer is configured.

Please suggest if I’ve missed something.